# increasing space between treeitems in gwt tree

Tags: css, gwt

I Am new to css and gwt widget styling.
I have a gwt tree widget and I want to increase the space between the treeitem s and also the size of each treeitem. What style should I apply to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every GWT widget has some styles applied to it. To find out which CSS classes have been applied to `Tree`, you should look at its [javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html). Notice the `CSS Style Rules` section:

> **.gwt-Tree**
>   the tree itself
>
> **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem**
>   a tree item
>
> **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem-selected**
>   a selected tree item

You most likely want to add some rules to the `.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem` rule:

```css
.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem {
    margin: 10px; /* Or maybe padding: 10px; */
    /* Increase the font size, etc. */
}
```

Put this in your CSS file or `<style>` section in your HTML file.

If you can't find the CSS classes in the javadoc, please use Firefox's Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools or whatever your browser provides to inspect the DOM and find out which classes are applied to the widget you are interested in. In some cases, of course, you might want to add your own styles, instead of overriding the GWT's ones - because if you override the GWT's, global ones all your widgets of that type will have this style applied. See the [Css Styling](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html) section in GWT's docs.